# How do I make this loop all children recursively?

Tags: javascript, recursion, loops, for-loop, children

I have the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
   if(hasClass(children[i], "lbExclude")){
       children[i].parentNode.removeChild(children[i]);
   }
};
```

I would like it to loop through all children's children, etc (not just the top level). I found this line, which seems to do that:

```
for(var m = n.firstChild; m != null; m = m.nextSibling) {
```

But I'm unclear on how I refer to the current child if I make that switch? I would no longer have i to clarify the index position of the child. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Update:

I'm now using the following, according to answer suggestions. Is this the correct / most efficient way of doing so?

```js
function removeTest(child) {
  if (hasClass(child, "lbExclude")) {
    child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
  }
}

function allDescendants(node) {
  for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var child = node.childNodes[i];
    allDescendants(child);
    removeTest(child);
  }
}

var children = temp.childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  allDescendants(children[i]);
};
```

Comment: Do you know how many arrays you have nested here?

Comment: Simply by the name `m`: `m.parentNode.removeChild(m)`. There might be a problem, though, because removing a node and then taking its `nextSibling` (in the `for` clause) will not work as intended.

Comment: @coshman, the amount of nested children will be variable.

Comment: @dirk I didn't think of that. Do you have a proposed way of dealing with that problem?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Normally you'd have a function that could be called recursively on all nodes. It really depends on what you want to do to the children. If you simply want to gather all descendants, then `element.getElementsByTagName` may be a better option.

```
var all = node.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = -1, l = all.length; ++i < l;) {
    removeTest(all[i]);
}
```

Comment: This will only get elements, not all nodes.

Comment: They are tested by a hasClass method however, so I believe they intend it to be elements.

Answer (score 59):

```
function allDescendants (node) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
      var child = node.childNodes[i];
      allDescendants(child);
      doSomethingToNode(child);
    }
}
```

You loop over all the children, and for each element, you call the same function and have it loop over the children of that element.

Comment: Sorry, could you be more explicit about how to apply this function in my case?

Comment: I think a more modern version of this would be `function allDescendants (node) {
    node.childNodes.forEach(child => {
    allDescendants(child);
    doSomethingToNode(child);
  });
}`

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for calling the 'allDescendants' method on all children, because the method itself already does that. So remove the last codeblock and I think that is a proper solution (á, not thé =])

```
            function removeTest(child){     
                if(hasClass(child, "lbExclude")){
                    child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
                }
            }

            function allDescendants (node) {
                for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
                  var child = node.childNodes[i];
                  allDescendants(child);
                  removeTest(child);
                }
            }           

            var children = allDescendants(temp);
```

Comment: The 'childNodes' it's was missing for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can use BFS to find all the elements.

```
function(element) {
    // [].slice.call() - HTMLCollection to Array
    var children = [].slice.call(element.children), found = 0;
    while (children.length > found) {
        children = children.concat([].slice.call(children[found].children));
        found++;
    }
    return children;
};
```

This function returns all the children's children of the element.

Answer (score 3):

To get **all** descendants as an array, use this:

```
function getAllDescendants(node) {
    var all = [];
    getDescendants(node);

    function getDescendants(node) {
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var child = node.childNodes[i];
            getDescendants(child);
            all.push(child);
        }
    }
    return all;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most clear-cut way to do it in modern browsers or with babel is this. Say you have an HTML node `$node` whose children you want to recurse over.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call($node.querySelectorAll("*"), function(node) {
  doSomethingWith(node);
});
```

The `querySelectorAll('*')` on any DOM node would give you *all* the child nodes of the element in a `NodeList`. `NodeList` is an array-like object, so you can use the `Array.prototype.forEach.call` to iterate over this list, processing each child one-by-one within the callback.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance! But, '$node' requires something like JQuery? Is this solution valid for a 'vanilla' javascript code?

Comment: No, $node is just a variable name holding an HTMLNode - don't get confused by the $ sign - any variable can have a $ in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have jquery and you want to get all descendant elements you can use:

```
 var all_children= $(parent_element).find('*');
```

Just be aware that `all_children` is an HTML collection and not an array. They behave similarly when you're just looping, but collection doesn't have a lot of the useful `Array.prototype` methods you might otherwise enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

if items are being created in a loop you should leave a index via id="" data-name or some thing.  You can then index them directly which will be faster for most functions such as  (!-F).  Works pretty well for 1024 bits x 100 items depending on what your doing.

```
if ( document.getElementById( cid ) ) {
 return;
} else {
  what you actually want
}
```

this will be faster in most cases once the items have already been loaded.  only scrub the page on reload or secure domain transfers / logins / cors any else and your doing some thing twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a js library it's as simple as this:

```
$('.lbExclude').remove();
```

Otherwise if you want to acquire all elements under a node you can collect them all natively:

```
var nodes = node.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  var n = nodes[i];
  if (hasClass(n, 'lbExclude')) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
}
```

Comment: whoops, didn't see @J-P's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
TreeNode node = tv.SelectedNode;
while (node.Parent != null)
{
    node = node.Parent;
}                    
CallRecursive(node);


private void CallRecursive(TreeNode treeNode)
{            
    foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
    {
        //Write whatever code here this function recursively loops through all nodes                 
        CallRecursive(tn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is remember that DOM is a `tree` structure. So, using the recursive approach, the idea is:

1. Process parent obj;
2. If obj has children(doesn't matter how many), iterate the children using `childNodes` function;
3. Inside iteration, call the same function recursively passing the child object

Ex:

```
function doSomething(obj) {
   // Processing parent obj here
   if(obj.childNodes !== undefined && obj.childNodes !== null) {
       obj.childNodes.forEach((c) => {
           doSomething(c)
       })
   }
}
```

Note that the 'obj' parameter on `doSomething` inside the iteration is actually the 'child' object. Thus, you are processing the child node for each interation which means at the end of the loop and all recursive calls, this code will process all nodes in the tree starting from 'obj'.

I hope it helps!