# jQuery .on() firing when addClass has been used

Tags: jquery

In the following code, I can't tell why my console prints 'hi' when I click on a button with the class 'edit-button' for the first time.  The second time I'm expecting it to print the console because the 'update-now' class has been added to the button.  Does anyone understand why this is? Thanks!

```
$(function() {
    $('.edit-button').on('click', function(e) {
      $( this ).addClass('update-now').html('Update');
    });
});



$(document).on('click', "div.update-now", function() {      
    console.log('hi');
});
```

Comment: Post a complete code example please, including your HTML.

Comment: FWIW, I took the time to put together jsFiddle demonstrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/2v8bcqv4/

Comment: Your first click event is bind to some button the second on the document. So at the time the document listener is called the button already has the class.

Comment: @RolandStarke No, the second `click` event is delegated to `div.update-now` elements.

Comment: It's executing the first click event before the second one, therefore it's adding the class, and then checking the class on the second click handler, which is coming back true, obviously

Comment: @RolandStarke I don't know what your point is? The event is delegated, and similarly from the jQuery docs: *The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector.*

Comment: @BenM take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15112421/5378743 he explains in his first example the event is bound to the div. So in the code we have here it is bound to document. But you sad "No" to that claim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because of event propagation. Basically event delegation works with the use of event bubbling. Now in your case, you bound an event to `.update-now` by using event delegation signature.

And you are adding a class `update-now` to another one button inside its click event, so that event propagates until it meets the document and after that it will investigate who raised the event. Here div with class `update-now` has started the propagation. So the event handler got triggered and prints hi in the console.

So if you stop the propagation after/before adding the class `update-now`, the `hi` message will not be printed,

```
$('.edit-button').on('click', function(e) {
  $( this ).addClass('update-now').html('Update');
  e.stopPropagation()
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2v8bcqv4/2/)

A solution for your case that i would suggest,

```
$('.edit-button').on('click', function(e) {
  $( this ).addClass('update-now').html('Update');
  $(this).off("click");
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('body').on('click', ".edit-button.update-now", function() {      
  alert('hi');
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2v8bcqv4/8/)

Comment: Except the `alert` is never triggered now, since the event does not propagate to `body`. (Try clicking the same element after its innerHTML is updated.

Comment: Using stopPropagation() stops the alert from happening always. You need to check to see if $(this) contains the update-now class - if so, do not stop the propagation

Comment: @mhodges I have given an explanation on why that `hi` was alerted. we can fix it in various ways. :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Please try your code. Click the "Update" text afterwards and see what happens. The `alert()` does not trigger: https://jsfiddle.net/2v8bcqv4/2/

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Rather confusing to an OP to give an answer that breaks what they are trying to do, without proposing a solution.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Perfectly valid as well, there are a million ways to skin this cat, I just wanted to make sure the OP got a solution ;)

Comment: @mhodges And i saw your edit, Why do we need to pull that unnecessary event listener with us. Right?

Comment: If that is all the listener is doing, agreed 100%. Hard to tell what the OP's full code looks like with just a minimal code example demonstrating the issue. If the original listener does other things, it needs to stick around.