# No propagation of 'addEventListener' on the future elements of the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to find a equivalent of `.on()` method of `jquery`.
My problem is with use of `addEventListener`, why can't I extend to all future elements of class?
What is the equivalent of `$("button").on("click", notify)` in javascript for future propagation?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112067/how-does-jquery-on-work and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814298/does-jquery-on-work-for-elements-that-are-added-after-the-event-handler-is-cre