# How to hide an element that is inserted to the page with external code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to hide an element that is inserted/injected to my Shopify store with an external app. It appears about a second later after everything has finished loading on the site and has a class called "hidethis" and a bunch of other elements.

This did not work and I have no idea what else to try.

```
$(".hidethis").hide();
```

I'm trying to hide this element based on the location of the user in the following manner:

```
 jQuery.ajax( {
  url: '//api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=xxx&fields=country_code',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {



    if (location.country_code === 'EE') {


  $(function() {
  // if geolocation suggest you need to hide, execute this as soon as possible
  var sheet = window.document.styleSheets[0];
  sheet.insertRule('.cart__options { display:none; }', sheet.cssRules.length);




})

  } 
 }
} );
```

Comment: Can we see the full markup of the added element?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: The main element has got a class called "hidethis". I think the other elements are not relevant. Maybe there is a way to make a function that checks for changes or constantly keeps scanning the page for new elements. I was able to hide the element when I edited the CSS from the developer view. Not sure why I'm getting downvoted.

Comment: Your copying of my example took too much of my test code. you just want `success: function(location) {
    if (location.country_code === 'EE') {
      var sheet = window.document.styleSheets[0];
      sheet.insertRule('.hidethis { display:none; }', sheet.cssRules.length);
    }
  }`

Comment: You can also reverse it and show it if it is NOT EE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution: CSS

```
.hidethis { display:none }
```

If this is not possible and you need JS

```
  var sheet = window.document.styleSheets[0];
  sheet.insertRule('.hidethis { display:none; }', sheet.cssRules.length);
```

```js
$(function() {
  // if geolocation suggest you need to hide, execute this as soon as possible
  var sheet = window.document.styleSheets[0];
  sheet.insertRule('.hidethis { display:none; }', sheet.cssRules.length);


  // test code - remove this when you insert the above code in your page
  setTimeout(function() {$("#container").append('<div class="hidethis">Hide this</div>');}, 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

which translates to your Ajax example:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '//api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=xxx&fields=country_code',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {
    if (location.country_code === 'EE') {
      var sheet = window.document.styleSheets[0];
      sheet.insertRule('.hidethis { display:none; }', sheet.cssRules.length);
    }
  }
})
```

Alternatively add a

```
<style>.hidethis { display:none }</style>
```

to the page before where the content you want to hide is going to appear. Then in your ajax do

```
if (location.country_code != 'EE') { $(".hidethis").show() }
```

---

You can also try an interval

```js
$(function() {
  var tId = setInterval(function() {
    var $hide = $(".hidethis");
    if ($hide.length>0) {
      clearInterval(tId);
      $hide.hide();
    }      
  },500);


  // test code - remove this when you insert the script in your page
  setTimeout(function() { $("#container").append('<div class="hidethis">Hide this</div>'); },1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: The second code worked but the element appears briefly. It's a solution but not the ideal desired result

Comment: I don't want to hide it for everyone. I'm checking the geolocation and trying to hide it based on the location of the user.

Comment: I seem to get this error - "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules". I probably messed it up trying to insert it into my code.

Comment: You likely need a stylesheet in the top of the page. I did not test if there was one

Comment: Please update the question. I cannot read the code in an unformatted comment

Comment: It is commented out. I added the code to my question.

Comment: $(function() {}) is a "page load" directive that does not belong in your ajax. Just add `var sheet = window.document.styleSheets[0];
  sheet.insertRule('.cart__options { display:none; }', sheet.cssRules.length)`

Comment: It still gives the same error though and there definitely are style sheets. It's a Shopify store...

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules

Comment: Then I suggest this: Add a `<style>.hidethis { display:none }</style>` to the page before where the content you want to hide is going to appear. Then in your ajax do `if (location.country_code != 'EE') { $(".hidethis").show() }`

Comment: Now we're back at the original problem. The code runs before the element gets added to the page and stays hidden.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to insert the style code into the page using jquery. So when the element gets injected it will either be visible or hidden depending on what jquery did based on the geolocation?

Comment: That is what I am trying to do from the start but you say it gives error on your page `var sheet = window.document.styleSheets[0];
      sheet.insertRule('.hidethis { display:none; }', sheet.cssRules.length);`

Comment: I didn't even realize... What if I create a new stylesheet that hides it. Can javascript call it if location.country_code == 'EE'?

Comment: Ok, that did the trick. I used $('head').append(). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sure, same idea as adding it to an existing stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Here an example how to add events: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48745137/155077

functional equivalent to jQuery `.on`.

Instead of adding an event-handler, you'll just have to hide it.

```
subscribeEvent(".feed", "click", ".feed-item", function (event) { /* here comes code of click-event*/ });
```

The whole thing works with MutationObserver:

```
// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
let config = { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
let observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(nodeToObserve, config);
```

where callback:

```
// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
let callback:MutationCallback = function (
    mutationsList: MutationRecord[], 
    observer: MutationObserver)
{
    for (let mutation of mutationsList)
    {
        // console.log("mutation.type", mutation.type);
        // console.log("mutation", mutation);

        if (mutation.type == 'childList')
        {
            for (let i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; ++i)
            {
                let thisNode: Node = mutation.addedNodes[i];
                allDescendants(thisNode); // here you do something with it
            } // Next i 

        } // End if (mutation.type == 'childList') 
        // else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') { console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');

    } // Next mutation 

}; // End Function callback
```

Comment: Sorry this one goes way above my head

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't actually about an element being added by an external app, the problem is that when your code to hide the element is executed the element isn't on the DOM yet. Because the element is being added sometime later after all your JavaScript code was already executed.

So, you have to execute your code after the element is added. One way to do that is by using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Here is a simple example using as referece the example in MDN:

```html
<div id="some-id"></div>
```

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            document.querySelector('.hide').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Add a timeout to simulate JavaScript being executed after all your code was executed.
setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById('some-id').innerHTML = '<span class="hide">Hello world</span>';
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: Are you trying to get the parent element where the .hidethis element will be? Are you using jQuery to get the element (jQuery doesn't return Node elements, you will have to do this $(selector)[0])?

Answer (score -1):

1 : at first , you inspect in your browser and find the element
2 : use $(document).ready() and hide that element